# Browsing the Qt 5.1.1 base source from within Visual Studio 2012 - Turning .pro into .sln files

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a .sln file of the Qt base sourcecode, for the purposes of looking at and learning more about the ins and outs of the Qt Source Base. What I assumed was quite straight forward has turned into being a tricky task.

I should clarify, I'm *not* trying to build a project using Qt quite yet - I am interested in looking at (and eventually) building the Qt SDK itself. The reason I'm emphasizing 'looking at' is because - for the time being - I would like to avoid installing numerous dependencies required to actually build Qt.

So far I've dropped by this page and downloaded the source:

http://qt-project.org/downloads

I then proceeded to boot up the MSVC Command prompt and run the configure.exe found in ./5.1.1/Src/qtbase.

At this point I did run nmake, fully aware that it would probably just start building Qt (which again - is not my goal). It did and failed somewhere along the way. Now I'm left in a state of limbo, unaware of how to create the .sln file that would contain the references and source from the Qt SDK.

I've learned that the .pro files are essentially what I need - just created for the Qt IDE. But searching for how to turn these .pro files into .sln only yielded a single result talking about using qmake.

I tried it like so:

qmake.exe qtbase.pro -tp vc

and wound up with numerous errors:

WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap\Qt5Bootstrap.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/tools/moc\moc.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/tools/rcc\rcc.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/corelib\Qt5Core.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/winmain\qtmain.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/network\Qt5Network.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/sql\Qt5Sql.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/xml\Qt5Xml.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/testlib\Qt5Test.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/concurrent\Qt5Concurrent.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler/preprocessor\preprocessor.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler\translator_common.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/angle/src/compiler\translator_hlsl.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/angle/src/libGLESv2\libGLESv2.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/angle/src/libEGL\libEGL.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/gui\Qt5Gui.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/platformsupport\Qt5PlatformSupport.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/openglextensions\Qt5OpenGLExtensions.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/tools/uic\uic.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/widgets\Qt5Widgets.vcxproj'
WARNING: Ignored (not found) 'D:/SDKS/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/Src/qtbase/src/opengl\Qt5OpenGL.vcxproj'

... The list goes on...

Not surprising giving that none of these vcxproj files actually exist... I am clueless as to what to do next. Any ideas?

Regards,
Gazoo

Comment: Learning about a framework by browsing it's source code is an interesting approach. Why not just creating some little projects to try different aspects. If you have the sources on your machine you can always debug those as well and see how the Qt framework works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this VS add-in: http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other
This allows you to open .pro files (it actually generates .sln files when opening them) and compile Qt projects. Qt sources are quite big though and you would probably need to open them a module at a time, because my VS cannot open the full src.pro but it can separate modules.

Comment: It feels to me as though it's still possible to convert the .pro files into .sln with only the use of qmake, but the add-in made everything work more or less. So thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: I tried `qmake.exe -tp vc Test.pro`, and It worked for a simple project

Comment: I made it work for a `corelib.pro` file as well, but not for `src.pro` in Qt sources